# How to provide texts to swagger in a properties file for spring restful service?

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger

I am creating my spring restful service documentation with swagger.

Sample request handler method and its documantation below. It works:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Returns user details", notes = "Returns a complete list of users details with a date of last modification.", response = User.class)
public Response getUser(@ApiParam(name = "userName", value = "Alphanumeric login to the application", required = true) @PathParam("userName") String userName) {
...
}
```

But I want to provide text of the request handler methods into swagger annotations from a properties file (It is being done to not increase the class size with documentation text).
 
Therefore I have created a properties file called "application-swagger.properties" and enabled it in "application.properties" (spring.profiles.active=swagger).
When I create api documentation as below, Text is not being displayed.

```
 application-swagger.properties:
 value=Returns user details
 notes=Returns a complete list of users details with a date of last modification.
```

Controller class:

```
@Controller
@Profile("swagger")
public class UserController{
    .
    .
    @ApiOperation(value = "${value}", notes = ${notes}", response = User.class)
    public Response getUser(@ApiParam(name = "userName", value = "Alphanumeric login to the application", required = true) @PathParam("userName") String userName) {
    ...
    }
    .
    .
}
```

Is there a way of putting text to swagger annotation from a properties file? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Swagger annotations do not allow to set "value, notes, nickname" keys with a variable. So I solved this problem using a static class and static final variables instead of properties file. For example, in request handler method "reqMethod1" value is set like: @ApiOperation(value = "SwaggerProps.REQMETHOD1_Value")

Comment: More info : This is not with swagger annotations only, with all annotations in general.

Comment: @ApiResponses(value = {
             @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully populated Emloyee Details ",response = Employee.class), - is there any option to pass code ,message value from application.properties instead of hardcode ? I am using springfox 2.9.x and Spring 4.3.15 - REST API

Answer (score 4):

It has been quiet late to answer the question but in case anyone needs help regarding the same may refer it.

Steps:

1. Create a property file, e.g. swagger.properties
2. Enter your desired messages as key-value pairs where key will be used as placeholder - e.g. person.id=Unique identifier of the person
3. Instead of annotation text insert a placeholder - e.g. ${person.id}
4. Register the property file in your configuration on class level - eg. @PropertySource("classpath:swagger.properties")

Worked with Spring Boot 1.5 and Swagger 2.8, not sure about the previous versions.

Reference taken from a detailed [article](https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/documenting-spring-boot-rest-api-swagger-springfox/) about the same.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it works as you've mentioned, but, unfortunately not for 'example' attribute. There you have to copy-paste values.

Comment: this work for the attribute "value" in ApiOperation annotation. Worked also for the attributes "name" and "value" in RequestMapping annotation. But sadely, did not work for the attribute "message" in ApiResponse annotation

Comment: is there any to way to pass runtime value to @ApiResponse(code =<config> , message=<config> )  using Spring 4

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this, as the annotation value expects a constant, but in your scenario it is not a constant.
Please refer the [accected values in the annotaion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) java doc, says it must be a constant.

The easiest/readable way to do this in your case is to move all the constants in a separate class instead of property file.