# dynamic values in tags object of swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I want to provide values from properties file in tags section of the swagger for ex:  tags = "${metric.tags}" but not able to pickup from properties file. for values it is working fine value = "${metric.value}".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Property Injection in a final attribute @Value - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7130425/113116), [How to provide texts to swagger in a properties file for spring restful service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41737779/113116), [swagger read documentation from properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58998687/113116), [Spring boot externalize config properties/messages on Java annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39107413/113116)

Comment: No. my question is for tags as mentioned it is working fine for value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have made plugin configuration in swagger configuration file and it started working as per my requirement.

@Bean
    public TranslationOperationBuilderPlugin translationPlugin() {
        return new TranslationOperationBuilderPlugin();
    }

    @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public static class TranslationOperationBuilderPlugin implements OperationBuilderPlugin {


        @Autowired
        Environment environment;

        @Override
        public boolean supports(DocumentationType delimiter) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void apply(OperationContext context) {

            String summary = context.operationBuilder().build().getSummary();
            String notes = context.operationBuilder().build().getNotes();
            Set<String>tags = context.operationBuilder().build().getTags();
            Set<String>translatedTags= new HashSet<>();
            for(String tag:tags) {
                if(environment.getProperty(tag)!=null) {
                    translatedTags.add(environment.getProperty(tag));
                }else {
                    translatedTags.add(tag);
                }
            }

            ModelReference modelReference= context.operationBuilder().build().getResponseModel();
            AllowableListValues allowableValues=(AllowableListValues) modelReference.getAllowableValues();
            if(allowableValues!=null && allowableValues.getValues()!=null) {
                List<String> translatedAllowables=new ArrayList<>();
                for(String value:allowableValues.getValues()) {
                    if(environment.getProperty(value)!=null) {
                        translatedAllowables.add(environment.getProperty(value));
                    }else {
                        translatedAllowables.add(value);
                    }
                }
                allowableValues.getValues().removeAll(allowableValues.getValues());
                allowableValues.getValues().addAll(translatedAllowables);
            }

            //String summaryTranslated = apiDescriptionPropertiesReader.getProperty(summary);
            //String notesTranslated = apiDescriptionPropertiesReader.getProperty(notes);
            //context.operationBuilder().summary(summaryTranslated);
            //context.operationBuilder().notes(notesTranslated);
            context.operationBuilder().tags(translatedTags);

        }
```